# string.replace does not work with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this string `dfdfd  dsfsdfsdfsdf {{random.number}} dsfdsfsdfsdf {{bla}}` and simple code that shold replace any `{{...}}` in a given string:

```
const b = template.replace(/\{{(.*)\}}/g, 'aaaa');
```

but nothing happened `template.replace` just does not work however the regex seems to be matching all `{{}}`

Any thougts?

**UPDATE:**

Just realized that my input string was wrong. Now I have all working with my original regex. However thanks to @Robo-Robok now I learned about `greedy` regexes and will be using his regex intstead.

Comment: Escape curly brackets `{}`. `\{\{(.*?)\}\}`

Comment: @S.Jovan why should he escape them?

Comment: @revo Here you [go](https://regex101.com/r/0DErUO/1)

Comment: I do not think there is anyting wrong with a regex as I am getting the matches http://regex101.com/r/0DErUO/2

Comment: Although your regex should be non-greedy `{{.*?}}`, the problem is not your regex if you don't see a match. Please show your receiving output.

Comment: There is no must in escaping braces. @S.Jovan

Comment: You want to replace the string inside `{{}}` or whole string with `{{}}`

Comment: Fyi there is just a must if you want to match something that looks like a quantifier such as [`{0}` literally -> `/\{0}/`](https://regex101.com/r/0DErUO/3). Also there is a must in [other regex flavors eg Java](http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyykk3m6r).

Comment: That "original regex" is not ok to accomplish what you really want.

Comment: thanks to all for help, really appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are greedy by default. Your `.*` eats as much as it can, which includes the first `}}` pair.

Try this instead:

```
const b = template.replace(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g, 'aaaa');
```

Question mark after `*`, `?` makes the match non-greedy.

Also two things:

1. It's better to escape all curly brackets. Your pattern will work well without escaping them, but it's a good idea to indicate that it's just a regular text.
2. Parentheses are redundant in your case, because you don't do anything with the catched string between curly braces.

Comment: OP's problem is not with greedy or non-greediness at the first place. He's stating no match not a mismatch.

Comment: I think it is. Greedy matching "works", because it matches something. But it catches all tags as one match. Problem needs to be described in more detail, but I believe it's about greediness.

Comment: Re-read the question *...but nothing happened*. But with his own regex something should happen for sure.

Comment: just realized I had wrong input string missing one `}`

Comment: @revo the problem is related to regex `greedy` because is swallowing the last part (from `{{`) till the end of the string `}}`.

Comment: Greediness was his second problem if he had a chance to solve first one. His first problem was not matching at all. See his comment above you. His input string was in wrong format. @Ele